# How to automatically set dictionary-style guide words at top of Microsoft Word Document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2016

At the top of each page in a printed dictionary, it's common to see *guide words* -- the first term and the last term that is defined on that page.

I would like to set up something like this in a dictionary-like Microsoft Word document, with the guide words set dynamically. In my document, each term is set to a specific style.

Is there a way to configure something in the page header that displays something like this:

{First text on page in a particular style} - {Last text on page in a particular style}

If not, then is there an alternative that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `StyleRef` field to create [dictionary-style headers](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm)

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to insert a field to represent the first text on the page. Edit the field to a `StyleRef` type and select the particular style that you have used for your guide words. For the last text on the page, select the `Search from bottom of page to top` option.

[image: StyleRef Field Editor]

The fields will show the entire paragraph contents of the first and last instances of your particular style.

[image: Dictionary-style guide words example]